# can I turn off Visual Studio's "[the file] is already open. Do you want to close it?" behavior?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I installed MVC3 today in VS2010. Since then, if I double click *some* items in Solution Explorer, I get this dialog:

[image]

It's intermittent but annoying as heck. It seems to be only happening for a few files. I can't imagine a situation where, when double clicking a file in Solution Explorer, I'd want that file to close. The files in question are all Razor views, but it's not happening for all Razor views, even if they are in the same directory. They all have the same file extension.

Can I disable this dialog and set it to always open a file that I double click in Solution explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted the computer and this issue went away.

Answer (score 2):

Closing VS and re-opening worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error still even though these had been reported many times in the past in Visual Studio Developer Community and are all marked fixed/closed.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Search-tells-file-is-already-open/10278575

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-document-is-already-open-do-you-want-to-close/780588

Even closing & opening the solution again, or System restarts, doesn't fix the problem for me.
What worked for me, is right click the file and choose **'Open With'** from context menu and select any other option but first (the default one).
Hope this helps!!